# WPF: Replace a branch of Visual Tree at run time with a sub XAML?

Tags: wpf

To simplify the question, I will describe a simplified use case:

Let's say I have a top level Grid that contains 1 dynamic inner Grid and a ListBox that fits in certain cells of the top level Grid:

1. The top level Grid structure (TopGrid.xaml) is relatively static with only dynamic size of the cell that will contain the inner Grid.
2. The inner Grid structure is dynamic, there are many/unkown kind of contents, but each kind of content is static and can be represented by a separate XAML. So I will have InnerGrid_1.xaml, InnerGrid_2.xaml, InnerGrid_n.xaml, etc.
3. At run time, depend on the ListBox selection, certain InnerGrid should be displayed.

I'm thinking of two ways to do it:

1. Run time text-edit the XAML in the code:
   In the code, use XmlDocument to edit the TopGrid.xaml to add the content of certain InnerGrid_x.xaml to create the final in-memory TopGrid.xaml. Then use XamlReader to read the final TopGrid.xaml into a Visual Tree, then add the tree to LayoutRoot to show it.
2. Visual Tree manipulation (no text edit):
   In the code, use XamlReader to read the TopGrid.xaml into a top-visual-tree, read InnerGrid_x.xaml into a sub-visual-tree. Then use VisualTreeHelper to find the TopGrid element in top-visual-tree, find the InnerGrid element in the sub-visual-tree. Then add the sub-visual-tree to the top-visual tree. Then add the combined tree to LayoutRoot show it.

I know the first way will work but need complex XML manipulation (or text editing) in the code. I desire the second way but not sure if it will work. Especially, I will probably change the size of the cell in the TopGrid to hold the dynamic InnerGrid.

Anybody has done this and can shed some light? or any better solution?

A side question: Seems the dynamically loaded XAML cannot specify event handler inside XAML (my test), I need set event handler dynamically after creating the tree. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

The WPF way is to just bind to your data and let WPF resolve the visual tree:

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeData}"/>
```

In order to render your content, WPF will look for a `DataTemplate` matching the type of data bound. So, for each type of data you have, you would define a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="...">
    <!-- your visual tree representing the data goes here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

You can also tell WPF explicitly how to represent your data by specifying the `ContentTemplate` property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeData}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyContentTemplate}"/>
```

TLDR: neither of your proposed approaches are idiomatic WPF. You should look into data templating.

Comment: Thanks, this helps! I just jump in WPF since a week ago and need satisfy quite a few requirements in a short time and so far I have found what I need! I need still get time to read WPF systematically!